# Insert multiple DB rows from listview - VB.NET MYSQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a listview that can contain up to roughly 2,000 listview items
I need to loop through the listview and insert each item into a mysql database

is there a better, bulk way, to insert the data instead of doing an insert for each item like follows:

```
for each itm ...
  insert into whatever ( id ) values ( itm.text ) ...
next
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build up a file containing the changes and then use the '`LOAD DATA INFILE`' functionality -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html